# cant remove an item from listbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to remove an item from listbox but is not working. even that im sure that there exist an item to remove. any idea about what maybe going wrong?

```
iSelectedItem = ContactConflictListBox.ItemIndex;


if ((iSelectedItem == -1))
{
    return;
}

ContactConflictListBox.Items.Remove(iSelectedItem);
```

Comment: Have you breakpointed the code to determine what's happening? I'd imagine not using the SelectedIndex property might be contributing to your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an index, not an item. To remove by index, use `ContactConflictListBox.Items.Remove(ContactConflictListBox.Items[iSelectedItem]);` or `ContactConflictListBox.Items.RemoveAt(iSelectedItem);`. Be aware, that the RemoveAt method shouldn't be used in code, it's just there for infrastructural reasons.

Comment: That was my first idea as well. Unfortunately the docs say *This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.*

Comment: @Strider007: In case you didn't see it, RemoveAt is not intended to be used directly, so it *might* impose compatibility problems in the future (though it's not likely). Just be aware of this.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (ListBox.SelectedItem!= null)
{
    ListBox.Items.Remove(ListBox.SelectedItem); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox.ObjectCollection.Remove` takes the *object* you want to remove as argument. You have to either call `ListBox.ObjectCollection.RemoveAt` (which is, unfortunately, documented as infrastructure-only), or pass the object to `ListBox.ObjectCollection.Remove`:

```
ContactConflictListBox.Items.Remove(ContactConflictListBox.Items[iSelectedItem]);
```

(or, in case the index is not relevant:)

```
ContactConflictListBox.Items.Remove(ContactConflictListBox.SelectedItem);
```